# No puedo añadir lista de Strings a un JLabel en Java

Tags: java, java-swing, jlabel

estoy haciendo una pequeña app de escritorio con Swing en Java y estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con el texto de un JLabel
Pongo un poco en contexto así es más fácil entender todo: La app es básicamente una especie de controlador de gastos de tarjeta de crédito, donde yo al agregar un "Total gastado" a un mes (enero, febrero, marzo...) los cuales cada uno de esos meses es una Tabla en una Base de Datos local, se debería de mostrar en un JLabel en el menu de la aplicación. Aquí les adjunto el código que hice para el método el cual realiza esta acción, o al menos debería.
(El código funciona si por ejemplo en vez de setear el text del JLabel, imprimo la información en la consola, pero no al querer colocarlo en el Label).

```
    public void mostrarPendientes(JLabel label) {
    String query = "";
    Connection con = null;
    con = ConexionBD.conectar();

    java.sql.Statement stm = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        for (Meses mes : Meses.values()) {
            query = ("select total from " + mes);
            stm = con.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery(query);

            if (rs.next()) {
                Float total = rs.getFloat("total");
                if (total > 0) {
                    String mesesTotales = (mes.toString() + " " + total);
                    ArrayList<String> mesesConTodo = new ArrayList<>();
                    mesesConTodo.add(mesesTotales);
                    System.out.println(mesesConTodo);
                    label.setText(label.getText() + "<html>" + mesesConTodo + "<br></html>");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

**Lo que deberia mostrar en el label:**

[image: Lo que deberia mostrar:]

**Lo que muestra:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el `JLabel` necesita un String, y tu estas intentando concatenar un String con un `ArrayList`. Necesitas generar un `String`.
Para poder hacerlo debes generar el `String` to mismo, iterando los elementos de tu `ArrayList` y posteriormente usándolos en el `setText` de tu `JLabel`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String mesConTodo : mesesConTodo)
    sb.append(mesConTodo + "</br>");

label.setText(label.getText() + "<html>" + sb.toString() + "<br></html>");
```

Comment: Buenas! hice lo que propusiste y lo mismo, muestra solamente un mes, pero en la consola muestra los 3 que tienen un total > 0

Comment: Ya pude arreglarlo! no use tu solución, cambie el for each por un for normal y utilice el indice del "i" para ir añadiendo cada uno de los meses (y algo muy importante es que utilice el label.getText() antes del mes asi no se pisaba todo le tiempo)

Answer (score 0):

¡Ya pude arreglarlo! Cambié el `for each` por un `for` normal y utilicé el índice del "i" para ir añadiendo cada uno de los meses (y algo muy importante es que utilicé el `label.getText()` antes del mes así no se pisaba todo el tiempo.)